# all combinations of DNA characters in a string of length 4

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I am trying to generate a list of all possible DNA sequences of length four with the four character `A`, `T`, `C`, `G`. There is a total of 4^4 (256) different combinations. I include repeats, such that `AAAA` is allowed. 
I have looked at `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)`
however, the list output changes depending on the order of the input string i.e

```
itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ATCG', 4) #diff results to...
itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ATGC', 4)
```

Because of this, I had an attempt at combining `itertools.combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r)`, with `itertools.permutations()`

Such that pass the output of `itertools.permutations()` to `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`. As defined below:

```
def allCombinations(s, strings):
perms = list(itertools.permutations(s, 4))
allCombos = []
for perm in perms:
    combo = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(perm, 4))
    allCombos.append(combo)
for combos in allCombos:
    for tup in combos:
        strings.append("".join(str(x) for x in tup))
```

However running `allCombinations('ATCG', li)` where `li = []` and then taking the 
`list(set(li))` still only proceeds 136 unique sequences, rather than 256.

There must be an easy way to do this, maybe generating a power set and then filtering for length 4?

Comment: `itertools.product('ATCG', repeat=4)`?

Comment: Post as answer and ill accept

Comment: It's very similar. But I believe the user in the link is asking for a sliding window of combinations across the string

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak It is basically the same as DeepSpace's answer, just shorter. So you can accept their answer, and they might edit their answer to include this alternative too.

Comment: No loaded modules, pure Python on one line: `sorted([ a+b+c+d for a in 'ATCG' for b in 'ATCG' for c in 'ATCG' for d in 'ATCG' ])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `product`. It gives the Cartesian product of the passed iterables:

```
a = 'ACTG'

print(len(list(itertools.product(a, a, a, a))))
# or even better, print(len(list(itertools.product(a, repeat=4)))) as @ayhan commented
>> 256
```

But it returns tuples, so if you are looking for strings:

```
for output in itertools.product(a, repeat=4):
    print(''.join(output))

>> 'AAAA'
   'AAAC'
   .
   .
   'GGGG'
```

Comment: Cheers Pal. I'll accept soon

Comment: ``[''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(a, repeat=4)]`` for comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You could just try this

```
l = []

s = 'ATCG'

for a in s:
    n1 = a
    for b in s:
        n2 = n1 + b
        for c in s:
            n3 = n2 + c
            for d in s:
                l.append(n3+d)
```

Comment: This *really* doesn't scale very well -- and isn't a good answer to a question which is looking for an itertools approach.

Comment: You're right, it does not. But sometimes you have to use what is best in the current situation, not just go with the best scalable option. This one is fairly easy to grasp.

Comment: "This one is fairly easy to grasp" Not quite. In order to understand what this code does one needs to mentally keep in mind and track around 8 different variables.

Comment: No, I'm not giving this as a "copy+paste"-example, however the concept of 4 nested for loops is something that is not programmatical but mathematical, and the concept of this is basic combinatorics. And then again thinking about now HOW but WHY to answer this question, is it to get a working oneliner? Understand ``itertools``? or maybe it is just an exercise from school...